# Comunication between processes using TCP (C++ / libuv)

Tags: c++, network-programming, libuv

I'm writing a program whose task is communication between the client and the server. the point is that the server runs in the background, and after starting the second program, the client connects via TCP and then sends it a message.
At the moment, analyzing the data collected by wireshark, I can say that I manage to establish a connection and send a packet with a message, the problem occurs when the server receives the message, the "on_read" function is not called.
Server code:

```
#include <uv.h>
#include <iostream>

void on_read(uv_stream_t* client, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t* buf)
{
    std::cout << "ANY DATA?\n";

    if(nread > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Received: " << std::string(buf->base, nread) << std::endl;
    }
    else if(nread < 0)
    {
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*)client, NULL);
    }
    free(buf->base);
}

void alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t* handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t* buf)
{
    buf->base = (char*)malloc(suggested_size);
    buf->len = suggested_size;
}

void on_new_connection(uv_stream_t* server, int status)
{
    if(status < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error on_new_connection: " << uv_strerror(status) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    uv_tcp_t* client = new uv_tcp_t();
    uv_tcp_init(uv_default_loop(), client);

    if(uv_accept(server, (uv_stream_t*)client) < 0)
    {
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*)client, NULL);
        return;
    }
    
    std::cout << "New connection accepted." << std::endl;
    uv_read_start((uv_stream_t*)&client, alloc_buffer, on_read);
}

int main()
{
    uv_tcp_t server;
    uv_tcp_init(uv_default_loop(), &server);

    struct sockaddr_in bind_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 7000, &bind_addr);

    if(int r = uv_tcp_bind(&server, (const struct sockaddr*)&bind_addr, 0); r < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error binding server: " << uv_strerror(r) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if(int r = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*)&server, 128, on_new_connection); r < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error starting server: " << uv_strerror(r) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Server started on port 7000." << std::endl;

    uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    return 0;
}
```

client code:

```
#include <uv.h>
#include <iostream>

void after_send(uv_write_t *req, int status)
{
    std::cout << status << "as\n";
}

void on_connect(uv_connect_t* req, int status)
{
    if(status < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error on_connect: " << uv_strerror(status) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "Connected to server." << std::endl;

    Sleep(1000);

    uv_buf_t buf = uv_buf_init("Hello, server!\r\n", 14);
    uv_write_t write_req;
    uv_write(&write_req, req->handle, &buf, 1, after_send);
}

int main()
{
    uv_tcp_t client;
    uv_tcp_init(uv_default_loop(), &client);

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("127.0.0.1", 7000, &serv_addr);

    uv_connect_t connect_req;
    uv_tcp_connect(&connect_req, &client, (const struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, on_connect);

    return uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

I want the server to display this message on the screen after the client sends a message

Comment: Why are you writing C++ like it's still the1990's with manual memory management and calls to C functions and in general code that looks like it missed the last 20-25 years of C++ evolution? And seriously, `malloc`? In a C++ program? Come on, `new` is bad, `malloc` is just .. I give up.

Comment: @JesperJuhl see that "New contributor" tag below the OP's name?  Be sure to read the tooltip that appears when you mouse over it.  New programmers need constructive help and encouragement, not to be criticized for not doing things "the right way", because of course they aren't following best practices; they are by definition still new at this and still learning what those are.

Comment: @Matthew I suggest printing out the value returned by your `uv_read_start()` call to verify that the call actually succeeded.  If it returned non-zero, that means the call failed (for some reason) and that could explain why your callback is not getting called when expected.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yup, uv_read_start returns -4048 :/ thank you and sorry for problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for your opinion, can you tell me more about the mistakes in my writing style? is malloc the only problem? I would like to improve my skills.

Comment: Handy reading: [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). Much wisdom in there, but remember: They are guidelines. Sometimes you need to break with them, but the only way to know when you should break with them is to know them.